# aws sdk for js seems to be missing support for credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to set the credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata option in the profile config file so applications/tools running on an EC2 can assume a specific role rather than the Instance Profile role.

Looking through the aws-sdk-js source code, I don't see any references to either credential_source and/or Ec2InstanceMetadata. Am I missing somthing?

Comment: It seems there is a feature request already open for this...
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1916

Answer (score 0):

Workaround posted on github, to use [ChainableTemporaryCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ChainableTemporaryCredentials.html) instead. Worked for me. Requires the use of specific ARN's instead of the profile names. Thanks to AllanFly120 on github!